# Angular controller returns blank in Html page in the double curly braces

Tags: angularjs, html, typescript, controller

I'm working on a simple binding application with typescript. I wrote a controller named 'bugCtrl' and it looks like working just fine in debug mode (also console.log and alert). this is my html page

```
<body ng-app="bugApp">
<div class="panel panel-primary" ng-controller="bugCtrl">
    <h3>Bug List</h3>
    <div>
        There are {{ test ? '1' : '2' }} bugs (div1)
    </div>
    <div>
        There are <span ng-bind="{{ workItems.length }}"></span> bugs (div2)
    </div>
    <div>
        Descriptions : <span ng-bind-template="{{ workItems[0].description }} {{ workItems[1].description }}"></span> (div3)
    </div>
    <div>
        There are {{ getLenght(); }} bugs (div4)
    </div>
    Display as Grid? <input type="checkbox"><br />
    <div class="well" ng-include="getView()"> </div>
    <!--<ng-include src="getView()"></ng-include>-->
</div>



<!-- Library Scripts -->
<script src="../../scripts/angular.js"></script>

<!-- Application Script -->
<script src="../bugApp.js"></script>

<!-- Services -->
<!--<script src="app/common/services/common.services.js"></script>-->
<!-- Controllers -->
<script src="../common/controllers/bugCtrl.js"></script>
```

Here is my controller and bugApp.js file:

```
module app {
    var bugApp = angular.module("bugApp",
        []);
}

module app.controller {
    interface IWorkItems {
        description: string;
        status: string;
        getView?(): string;
    }

class BugCtrl  {
    workItems: Array<IWorkItems>;
    test: string;

    constructor($scope, $timeout) {

        this.workItems = [
            { description: "Severe bug", status: "Open" },
            { description: "Minor bug", status: "Closed" }
        ];
        this.test = "BBB";

        alert(this.workItems[0].description);
        console.log(this.workItems.length.toString());
        console.log(this.workItems[0].description);
    }


    getLenght(): string {
        return this.workItems.length.toString();
    }
}

angular
    .module("bugApp")
    .controller("bugCtrl", BugCtrl);
}
```

It seems pretty simple yet I cannot resolve the problem here. And this is 
[the result I get:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNiwF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `this` keyword, you need to use the `controllerAs` syntax :

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" ng-controller="bugCtrl as vm">
```

and all of your ng-models will have :

```
<td>There are {{ vm.test ? '1' : '2' }} bugs (div1)</td>
```

I see that you have a `$scope` dependency. You can, instead of `this`, use `$scope` to name your variables :

```
$scope.workItems = [
            { description: "Severe bug", status: "Open" },
            { description: "Minor bug", status: "Closed" }
        ];
```